# OpenOffice Calc: Cell Background/Border Color

Tags: colors, openoffice-calc

I am trying to create a spreadsheet with **colored cell backgrounds**. But I encountered this strange bug, where the background of a cell is bigger than the shown border, so coloring a cell will actually color a **very slim margin in the cell next to it**. :/

Here is an example of what I mean (zoomed in):

[image: Screenshot of the PDF]

Note that what you see here is the created PDF, so this is not just an issue with Calcs representation!

- As you can see the blue cell *stretches* into the cells above and to the left, but strangely not to the bottom.
- Furthermore there is a very faint *grey line* as border between some black cells. This is strange as I certainly never used any grey colors for cell borders. Also the line is only visible in the PDF (or in the OOCalc preview) *on certain zoom levels*.

Any idea on how to fix this? Am I missing something?

(Only way around it up to now has been to add quite thick borders to cover up the error, but that is an ugly hack...)